# kivy gridlayout child position after resizing window

Tags: python, kivy

im new  to kivy , i'm trying to make an 8puzzle game, my problem is , after moving the numbers(using Buttons or labels) in a gridlayout (using animation calss to move the buttons) there is no problem till resizing the window ! after resizing window every button or label will be in it's initial position :-/ 
so,why gridlayout children come back to the initial position after ressizing the window ? 
how can i fix this ?

```
python code :
class Cubes(Button):
    #value=StringProperty('0')
    pos_i=NumericProperty(0)
    pos_j=NumericProperty(0)


class Puzzle(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Puzzle,self).__init__()

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None,self)

        print("Tsfsdfsdfdsfsdfdsf")
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        game =[
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,"-"]
        ]
        for i in range (3):
            for j in range (3):
                self.add_widget(Cubes(text=str(game[i][j]),pos_i=i,pos_j=j))


        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.move)
        self.wait=False

        self._index=-1
        self._solution=[]



    def move(self, keyboard, keycode, text,modifires):



        pos=-1

        for i in range(9):
            if self.children[i].text=="-":
                pos=self.children[i].pos
                self._index=i



        #print (self.children[self._index].pos)     
        if keycode[1]=="up":
            if Expand(Node(self.generatePuzzleTable())).CanGoUp():
                for m in range(9):
                    if self.children[m].pos_i==self.children[self._index].pos_i-1:
                        if self.children[m].pos_j==self.children[self._index].pos_j:
                            self.replace(self.children[m].pos,self.children[self._index].pos,m)
                            break

        if keycode[1]=="right":
            if Expand(Node(self.generatePuzzleTable())).CanGoRight:
                for m in range(9):
                    if self.children[m].pos_i==self.children[self._index].pos_i:
                        if self.children[m].pos_j==self.children[self._index].pos_j+1:
                            self.replace(self.children[m].pos,self.children[self._index].pos,m)
                            break

        if keycode[1]=="down":
            if Expand(Node(self.generatePuzzleTable())).CanGoDown():
                for m in range(9):
                    if self.children[m].pos_i==self.children[self._index].pos_i+1:
                        if self.children[m].pos_j==self.children[self._index].pos_j:
                            self.replace(self.children[m].pos,self.children[self._index].pos,m)
                            break                   
        print (keycode[1])
        if keycode[1]=="enter":
            self.ans()

        if keycode[1]=="left":
            if Expand(Node(self.generatePuzzleTable())).CanGoLeft():
                for m in range(9):
                    if self.children[m].pos_i==self.children[self._index].pos_i:
                        if self.children[m].pos_j==self.children[self._index].pos_j-1:
                            self.replace(self.children[m].pos,self.children[self._index].pos,m)
                            break

        if keycode[1]=="spacebar":
            print ("what the fuck ?!? ",keycode[1])
            self.solve()



    def replace(self,pos,pos1,NodeIndex):
        anime=Animation(pos=(float(pos[0]),float(pos[1])),d=0.2,t="out_cubic")#.start(self.children[0])
        anime.start(self.children[self._index])
        anime2=Animation(pos=(float(pos1[0]),float(pos1[1])), d=0.2,t="out_cubic")#.start(self.children[1])
        anime2.start(self.children[NodeIndex])
        ti=self.children[self._index].pos_i
        tj=self.children[self._index].pos_j
        self.children[self._index].pos_i,self.children[self._index].pos_j=self.children[NodeIndex].pos_i,self.children[NodeIndex].pos_j
        self.children[NodeIndex].pos_i,self.children[NodeIndex].pos_j=ti,tj
```

kivy code :

```
<Cubes>:
    background_color: 1,1,1,1


<Puzzle>:
    cols: 3
    spacing: 2
    size: (300, 300)


BoxLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: (0.7, 0.3, .4)
        Rectangle:
            pos: (self.x, self.y)
            size: (self.width, self.height)
    size: (600, 600)
    AnchorLayout:
        Puzzle:
            center_x: root.center_x
            center_y: root.center_y*2/3
```

[in this image i moved the dash button to top left , but i resize the window 
it will be in it's initial position (bottom right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCgPu.png)

Comment: Please show us what code you've written so far and mention (through screenshots if needed) what your current output is, and what your desired output might be.

Comment: i've edited the post

Comment: do not mark questions *solved* in the title, this is **not** a forum, you mark answers as helpful with an up vote, you mark them as accepted with the checkmark if they solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridLayout (or any Layout for that matter) is responsible for positioning its children widget so on each re-size (and other meaningful events) the layout will position the widgets from scratch (this is the behavior that annoys you).

In the case of GridLayout, what matters is the order of the children of the grid...

To fix your issue you have two two options:

1) after your animation is complete swap the "-" widget with other one on the grid children list.

2) use something like https://github.com/inclement/sparsegridlayout that lets you specify what is the (i,j) for each widget(grid entry)

I hope this makes things a bit more clear